# Session not destroyed when closing browser - RailsTutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication, railstutorial.org

In working through Michael Hartl's railstutorial.org, I'm in Chapter 8 (specifically 8.2.3). The current problem is implementing a session to keep the user logged in across multiple views, but the functionality implemented in this section is supposed to be a *temporary* session that expires (logs the user out) when the browser window is closed. Here is the statement from the textbook indicating such:

> If you quit your browser completely, you should also be able to verify that the application forgets your login status, requiring you to log in again to see the changes described above.

I've tested this functionality on both Google Chrome and Firefox -- I log in successfully, navigate to multiple pages (to make sure my session persists beyond the log_in redirect) and then close the browser -- but when I reload the web app, I'm still logged in. I've copied all the code **exactly** as its written in the text, but to no avail. For reference, here's my `sessions_helper.rb` file:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

end
```

And here is my `sessions_controller.rb` file (the `destroy` action has not been implemented yet, since I haven't gotten to the point in the text of giving the Logout button any functionality):

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      # Log the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
```

end

**Note:** In your answer(s), please **do not** suggest adding alternate code or changing existing code (unless you see a mistake with the code I've posted). The textbook assumes this is working code and doesn't need any alteration for it to properly function.

Answer (score 6):

Please, check your `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file. There should be something like

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

You have to add `expire_after` key with `nil` value to the options:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', expire_after: nil
```

After applying this change, the session will expire when user closes the browser. You can read more about cookies expiration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and added `expire_after: nil` to my `session_store.rb` file and it still persists the log-in after closing the browser and loading the site in a new browser session. I even tried manually stopping the server and restarting it and reloading the page and my user is still logged in. I don't know if it makes a difference or not, but I'm using c9.io to host this project and serve the page via the built-in WEBrick server. However, I load the site pages in a new browser tab rather than within the c9.io web app. Would this make a difference at all?

Comment: FWIW, I've tried this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE. In both Chrome and Firefox, the session persists after the browser is restarted. In IE, the session is expired and I have to re-login when a new browser window is opened (which is the correct behavior).

Comment: You should do this in this way: apply changes (`expire_after: nil`), restart the server, logout. After next login the session should expire after browser close. The wanted behaviour can be simply checked - the cookie with name, mentioned in the `config/initializers/session_store.rb` (in my example it is `'_app_session'`) should not have expire time.

Comment: About c9.io - I am not aware of its behaviour at all. And why don't you use your own PC?

Comment: So there is no effective solution to this problem then, except of course, setting an expire time?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm chiming in a good seven months late, but I had this same question, and after a little extra googling, discovered it was answered two years ago [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/20449641/rails-4-session-value-never-expires-or-dies-when-browser-closes).

The problem is a browser setting, one I imagine most everyone uses these days: "When Firefox starts, show my windows and tabs from last time" or "On startup, continue where you left off." This issue is now mentioned as a footnote in the tutorial ([Chapter 8, Note 1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/basic_login#cha-8_footnote-1)), but the best the author has to say about it is

> ...of course Rails has no control over this behavior.