# Why is session not vanishing when the browser window is closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

As mentioned in chapter 8 of **Ruby on Rails Guide** by **Michael Hartl** a session gets deleted when the browser window is closed. I have tried using both Chrome and Firefox but the session does not gets deleted.

I am using the following login helper function:

```
def log_in user  
  session[:user_id]=user.id  
end
```

and the `session_store.rb` file contains the following code:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_sample_app_session'
```

I figured out that for a particular expiration **time**

```
:expire_after => 60.minutes
```

can be used but what is to be done if we want to expire the session as soon as the browser window is closed?

Comment: Since you are using cookie store, you might wanna check the cookie's expiration settings.

Comment: where to check cookie's expiration setting?

Comment: Try `:expire_after => nil`. [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32630220/157328)

Comment: @Leventix - this is a default value.

Comment: @Leventix: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L195

Comment: That value [goes into the cookie's expires](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L351) where `nil` means expire when browser is closed. It might be easier to try  setting a simple cookie and checking DevTools Network tab for the `Set-Cookie` header.

Comment: wait a second: by "browser window is closed" you mean there are other open windows of the same browser? That would explain it, as cookies without expiry are deleted when the browser application is closed (i.e. the browser session ends).

Comment: @Leventix by saying "browser window is closed" i meant "browser application is closed" and i tried using :expire_after => nil , it is not working. I even tried restarting the rails server after i closed the browser application then too it is showing the same logged in session which should have expired.

Comment: @Aman Khare: make sure you also clear the cookies before you do a new test; changing the Rails config might not affect cookies that have already been set

Comment: @Leventix I did that too.

Comment: Are by any chance using Chrome and have the "Remember where I left off" setting on? [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies)