# Rails session doesn't expire at browser close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies

It's my understanding that the default behavior of Rails, when storing a session e.g. `session[:id] = 1`, is that it will save the id to a cookie, which will expire when the user closes the browser window. However, in my app, when I close (exit out) the browser and restart it, the browser still 'remembers' me as being logged in. Here is my controller code:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:notice] = "Invald email / password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

and my helper file:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def user_name
    @current_user.first_name ? (@current_user.first_name + " ") : nil
  end

end
```

I have nothing in the application controller nor did I ever mess with the initializers or config files regarding the session. What could be causing my session to persist and not expire the cookie?

Answer (score 0):

Withing `config/initializers/session_store.rb` file add

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session', expire_after: nil
```

Instead of

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_app_session'
```

Please have a look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply turn off cookies or reset cookies, which results in a new session being created with each visit. The solution looked like this:

- On client side, write a beforeunload event handler.
- From that handler make an AJAX request to logout URL, in your case it
  might be a special view that deletes the cookie (see Rails docs on
  cookies).
- The AJAX request has to be synchronous to make sure beforeunload
  event handler waits for its completion.

refer this https://codedecoder.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/clear-session-or-cookie-browser-close-ruby-jquery/ it might also help

Comment: I know how to expire the session. My question is regarding why the session isn't expiring when it's supposed to. Ryan Lue answered my question in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32621473/session-not-destroyed-when-closing-browser-railstutorial-org